# What algorithm does this sorting method use?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

```
import sys
final_set = []
init_set = []
for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
    init_set.append(sys.argv[i])
for i in range(len(init_set)):
    cur_min = min(init_set)
    final_set.append(cur_min)
    init_set.remove(cur_min)
print final_set
```

This fairly basic sorting algorithm must already have a name. Can anyone identify it and its time complexity?

Comment: Note that those are lists, not sets.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really thinking when I named them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), which has quadratic complexity.

Comment: On all counts of operations that I performed the operation count was less than n^2. Why is this? Is n^2/2 considered the same thing as n^2 in algorithmic complexity?

Comment: @user1419802 Checking the minimum has to go through each element.

Comment: Since one item of the list is removed each time the set becomes one smaller meaning that the first iteration takes n operations, the next takes n-1 operations and so on. That would presumably be less than n^2.

Comment: @user1419802 The mathematical definition of big-o complexity doesn't consider an exact count of operations, but rather how the number of operations *grows*. So, to estimate it empirically, you need to look at the operation count across several (preferably as many as practical) ns. But yes, an algorithm which always has n^2/2 operations is order n^2.

Comment: @user1419802 likewise, an algorithm that always has exactly twelve operations is called O(1) rather than O(12). Multiplying or dividing by a constant factor doesn't change the complexity (which is something you can prove if you decide to look at the math behind it), so we tend to just leave those out.

Comment: @user1419802 You're right - it takes (n-1)^2 operations - which is still O(n^2). To make the constant factor even worse, `remove()` requires time proportional to the number of elements after the element being removed.